# How to place an entry field next to label correctly using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have got a problem with spacing entry fields in window. It places not next to the label.

I tried to change numbers of rows and colomns to place it right next to labels, bit it doesn't work. Now these fields just levitate.
[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPTnx.png)
Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk


class Window(Tk):
    is_reset = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("720x465+760+200")
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.title("Калькулятор СМО")
        self.icon = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
        self.iconphoto(False, self.icon)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
        self.notebook.grid()

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.frame1.grid()
        self.frame2.grid()
        self.frame3.grid()
        self.notebook.add(self.frame1, text="Одноканальна СМО з відмовами")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame2, text="Багатоканальна СМО з відмовами")
        self.notebook.add(self.frame3, text="Одноканальна СМО з очікуванням з обмеженою чергою")


    def make_frame1(self):
        intensity_lambda_label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Введіть інтенсивність λ", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        intensity_lambda_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        intensity_lambda_entry = ttk.Entry()
        intensity_lambda_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
        intensity_miu_label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Введіть інтенсивність μ", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        intensity_miu_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
        intensity_miu_entry = ttk.Entry()
        intensity_miu_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)


    def run(self):
        self.make_frame1()
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    window.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `tk.Label`s are in `frame1`, when you `.grid()` them in the frame, it puts them in the frame. When you put the `Entry` in root, it `.grid()`s them in root.

You can fix it by moving the `Entry` into `frame1` when you create them like so:

`ttk.Entry(self.frame1)`

All in all it would look like this:

```py
        intensity_lambda_label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Введіть інтенсивність λ", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        intensity_lambda_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        intensity_lambda_entry = ttk.Entry(self.frame1)
        intensity_lambda_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
        intensity_miu_label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Введіть інтенсивність μ", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        intensity_miu_label.grid(column=0, row=2)
        intensity_miu_entry = ttk.Entry(self.frame1)
        intensity_miu_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

Comment: @arctg30 No problem. Glad I could help. Make sure to accept my answer if it answered your question.